# WordPress: Custom Query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, array-merge

I have a custom query that uses an array merge so I can list articles and custom post type posts in one list, showing 5 at a time. Pagination below allows the user to see the rest of the results. I keep getting pagination errors, but I've tried virtually every variation of the $paged variable in my query to get pagination to work and it doesn't. I know it's me, and probably a simple syntax thing...but I'm stumped. Any ideas? (Note: this page has multiple, other custom queries above the one in question)

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$loop1 = array_merge( $wp_query->query, 
                      array( 'post_type' => array('post','podcasts', 'cat' => $cat_ID ), 
                             'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 ), 
                             'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); 
query_posts( $loop1 );
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Does your ternary operator work the way you hope inside the array?

Comment: Also, you might try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion very much, but just tried it and sadly it did not work.